# Who wrote down minus times minus is equal to plus?

Tags: mathematics, terminology, notation, mathematical-logic

I am not here to ask why "minus times minus is plus", this is a basic arithmetic fact. The related question most people ask is: *why* does $-\times-=+$. Of, course there may be several explanations for this fact. But I want to know who first wrote down that particular rule? Is there any historical evidence in some papers or books where it appeared for the first time?

Comment: Diophantus in his Arithmetika

Comment: This question is answered here http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2631/historically-how-did-people-define-multiplication-for-negative-numbers Earliest written references are Liu Hui and Diophantus in 3rd century AD, in practice the rule was known earlier at least in China.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [Diophantus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantus) (born probably sometime between AD 201 and 215; died aged 84, probably sometime between AD 285 and 299) [Arithmetica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetica), see :

- Thomas Heath, [Diophantus of Alexandria : A Study in the History of Greek Algebra](https://books.google.it/books?id=jbY8AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA130) (1910), page 140 :

> A minus multiplied by a minus makes a plus; a minus multipliedby a plus makes a minus ; and the sign of a minus is a truncated $\Psi$ turned upside down, thus $\Lambda$ [with a third central leg]. [*Footnote*. The literal rendering would be "A wanting multiplied by a wanting makes a forthcoming."]

See also :

- Thomas Heath, [A History of Greek Mathematics. Volume II](https://books.google.it/books?id=41s9fPYjxJQC&pg=PA459) (1921), page 459 :

> For subtraction alone is a sign used. The full term for *wanting* is λείψις  as opposed to ύπαρξις, a *forthcoming*, which denotes a *positive* term.  The symbol used to indicate *wanting*, corresponding to our sign for *minus*, is $\Lambda$ [with a third central leg]，which is described in the text as a ‘$\Psi$ turned downwards and truncated’.The description is evidently 
>   interpolated, and it is now certain that the sign has nothing to do with $\Psi$.Nor is it confined to Diophantus, for it appears in practically the same form in Heron's *Metrica* [...].

---

Clearly, also if the rule is "correctly described", there is no hint to its modern symbolic formulation for lack of the modern symbols, that dates to the late 16th- early 17th Centuries.

For the modern version, see :

- [John Wallis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Wallis) (23 November 1616 – 28 October 1703), [A Treatise of Algebra](https://books.google.it/books?id=EuzpN1t5SOcC&pg=PA78) (1685), page 78-79 :

> Unde patet ratio tum hujus regulae, $+$ in $+$ facit $+$; tum hujus $-$ in $+$ facit $-$. [...] Indeque patet ratio tum hujus regulae, $+$ in $-$ facit $-$; tum hujus, $-$ in $-$ facit $+$.

The "justification" is that to *multiply* a given quantity by a *positive* factor is *ponendi* ("ubi $+2$ significat *bis ponere*") while to *multiply* it by a *negeative* factor is *tollendi* ("ibidem $-2$ est *bis tollere*, seu *bis ponere contrarium*").

> Contra vero, $-A$ per $-2$ multiplicare, est bis tollere $-A$, seu defectum $-A$ bis supplere, quod est $+A$ bis ponere, facitque $+2A$, (adeoque $-$ in $-$ facit $+$.)

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_number):

> By the 7th century, Indian mathematicians such as Brahmagupta were describing the use of negative numbers. Islamic mathematicians further developed the rules of subtracting and multiplying negative numbers and solved problems with negative coefficients.